# SQL Joining on column with unique values in left and right tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am stuck on a join, and I think I am not using the right type of join.

I have table1:

| ID | Time | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 08:00 | Rate Verify |
| 1 | 1/1/23 09:00 | Rate Verify |
| 1 | 1/1/23 12:00 | Rate Verify |
| 1 | 1/1/23 16:00 | Rate Change |

and table2:

| ID | Time | Total Downloaded |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 08:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 1/1/23 09:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 1/1/23 11:00 | 40 |
| 1 | 1/1/23 17:00 | 95 |

and want to join the tables like so:

| ID | Time | Action | Total Downloaded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 08:00 | Rate Verify | 10 |
| 1 | 1/1/23 09:00 | Rate Verify | 20 |
| 1 | 1/1/23 11:00 | null | 40 |
| 1 | 1/1/23 12:00 | Rate Verify | null |
| 1 | 1/1/23 16:00 | Rate Change | null |
| 1 | 1/1/23 17:00 | null | 95 |

I have tried:

```
from table1
left join table2 on (table1.id=table2.id) and     (table1.time=table2.time or table1.time is null or      table2.time is null)
```

This however excludes times from table2 that do not exist in table1

Thank you in advance for your advice

Comment: Hi - so what happened when you tried the other types of joins as listed in the documentation? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
with table1 as (
select *
from (values(1,'1/1/23 08:00','Rate Verify'),
            (1,'1/1/23 09:00','Rate Verify'),
            (1,'1/1/23 12:00','Rate Verify'),
            (1,'1/1/23 16:00','Rate Change'))x(id,time,action)
), table2 as (
select *
from (values(1,'1/1/23 08:00',10),
            (1,'1/1/23 09:00',20),
            (1,'1/1/23 11:00',40),
            (1,'1/1/23 17:00',9))x(id,time,total_download)
)
select coalesce(t1.id,t2.id) as id,
       coalesce(t1.time,t2.time) as time,
       t1.action,
       t2.total_download
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.time = t2.time
order by time;
```

Comment: the full outer join with coalesce is exactly what I was missing. Thank you Mike!